# /SourceCache/GoogleMobileMaps/GoogleMobileMaps-217.2/googlenav/mac/Loader.mm:194 Incorrect protocol version. We got 15393, but were expecting 14

Tags: iphone, mapkit

Any one knows what this exception means?

/SourceCache/GoogleMobileMaps/GoogleMobileMaps-217.2/googlenav/mac/Loader.mm:194 Incorrect protocol version. We got 15393, but were expecting 14.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The wifi connectivity was not authorized and I got a Parse Error because all my HTTP requests returned a login page when a response object was expected.

This exception occured when google maps was trying to update my current location.

Hope this answer helps someone.

Comment: Same here. I was on university network that requires login and I hadn't logged in yet.